# the backslash in the makefile rule "$(MODULES): \"

Tags: makefile

thanks. The below is part of a gnu makefile. I can understand most except the backslash in the row "$(MODULES): \". This line means the four libraries depend on ...what?
Thanks a lot. :)

```
MODULES     = diskfree.so issue.so processes.so time.so

$(MODULES): \
%.so:           %.c server.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as if there would be no backslash and new line:

```
$(MODULES): %.so: %.c server.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $<
```

That is, it's a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). Each target listed in `$(MODULES)` is made using `%.so: %.c` pattern rule and also depends on `server.h`.